# is it good to settimeout to hold state update?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, settimeout

I had to show fading out of `OutterNav` when clicked on it and open a model in its place and all this should have transition.

so what I did was to add the `className` on click of the `OutterNav` to show the `scale` and `fade` transition of `OutterNav` . But the opening of modal was based on `state` value which changed on click of `OutterNav`. So I added a `delay` in state update using `setTimeout`.

I had a question that if it is a good way to hold state update in such scenario or there is a good way to do it?

here is some code for reference

```js
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

const OutterNav = ({ setShowInnerNav }) => {
    const containerRef = useRef(null);

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            containerRef.current.classList.add(
                "search-widget-container-animation"
            );
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            setShowInnerNav(true);
        }, 300);  //is it okay....?
    };

    return (
        <div
            className='search-widget-container'
            ref={containerRef}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <button className='btn'>
                <span className='btn-text'>Anywhere</span>
            </button>
            <button className='btn'>
                <span className='btn-text'>Any week</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AirbnbOutterNav;
```

Comment: Adding a class like that is.a bad practice, but the timeout is fine

Comment: So what can be a better way of adding a class... As I have always encountered people doing it same way around me.